# How do I vectorize this is_prime function in R?

Tags: r, function, vectorization, primes

I have created this function that takes number and return TRUE or FALSE depending whether the number is prime or not.

```
is.prime <- function(num) {
   if (num == 2) {
      TRUE
   } else if (any(num %% 2:(num-1) == 0)) {
      FALSE
   } else { 
      TRUE
   }
}
```

However, this function takes only one value, for example this works fine:

```
> is_prime(17)
[1] TRUE
```

If I plug in a vector, I want to see TRUE or FALSE for each element. For example,

```
> is_prime(c(17,5,10,22,109,55))
[1] TRUE
Warning messages:
1: In if (x == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In 2:(floor(x/2)) :
  numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used
3: In x%%2:(floor(x/2)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

This is evaluated for the first element, but I would want to see

```
TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

for the vector

```
is_prime(c(17,5,10,22,109,55))
```

How would I modify the function to vectorize using the same algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Half Vectorized

It is possible to vectorize some of the function by dealing with even numbers (and a few other numbers) in a vectorized fashion. The rest is taken care of using `vapply`.

```
helper <- function(x) {
  for (k in seq(3, round(sqrt(x)) + 1, 2)) {
    if (x %% k == 0)
      return(FALSE)
  }
  return(TRUE)
}
is.prime <- function(v) {
  out <- rep(TRUE, length(v))
  out[v %% 2 == 0 | v %in% c(1)] <- FALSE
  out[v %in% c(2, 3, 5)] <- TRUE
  indices <- which(v > 5 && v == FALSE)
  out[indices] <- vapply(v[indices], helper, logical(1))
  return(out)
}
is.prime(c(17,5,10,22,109,55))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

## Full Vectorized

If performance is at stake, you might consider using `Rcpp`:

**c++ file**

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


bool is_prime(int n) {
  if ((n == 2) || (n == 3) || (n == 5)) {
    return true;
  }
  if ((n % 2 == 0) || (n == 1)) {
    return false;
  }
  int i = 3;
  while (i < round(sqrt(n)) + 1) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    i += 2;
  }
  return true;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalVector is_prime(IntegerVector v) {
  int n = v.length();
  LogicalVector out = LogicalVector(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    out[i] = is_prime(v[i]);
  }
  return out;
}
```

**R File**

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp('prime_fun.cpp')  # if cpp file in same dir
is_prime(c(17,5,10,22,109,55))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you cannot vectorize the function but you can use methods to apply `is.prime` function to vectors.

For example, use `sapply` :

```
sapply(c(17,5,10,22,109,55), is.prime)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or use `Vectorize` which is a wrapper around `mapply` :

```
vec.is.prime <- Vectorize(is.prime)
vec.is.prime(c(17,5,10,22,109,55))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

R is an inherently vectorized language, you just have to not break that when you write functions...

```
is.prime <- function(num){
  res<-rep(TRUE, length(num))
  for(i in 2:(max(num)-1) ){
    res[(i < num) & ((num %% i) == 0) ] <- FALSE
  }
  return(res)
}

x<-c(2, 5, 17, 109, 10, 22, 55, 93)

print("Primes:")
print(x[ is.prime(x) ] )
```

Output:

```
> source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
[1] "Primes:"
[1]   2   5  17 109
```